# Как убрать пустые места фона

Tags: javascript, html, css, веб-программирование

Столкнулась с проблемой адаптации заднего фона под сайт. При изменении ширины экрана появляются пустые места под картинкой, из-за которых я не могу добавить другие блоки сайта. Пробовала по разному, но ничего не меняется. Заказчик просит, чтобы задний фон пропорционально уменьшался в размерах, поэтому `cover` предлагать не нужно, `contain` делает то, что надо.

*Стандартный вид (все выглядит круто):*

[image: Картинка]

*Так это выглядит на телефоне(огромное пустое место под картинкой):*

[image: Картинка]

```css
.firstblock_background {
    border: solid #000;
    max-width: 100%;        
    height: 810px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    z-index: 4;
    background: url(../source/block/background.png) center top/contain no-repeat;
}

&__woman{
        position: absolute; 
        right: 3%;
        overflow: hidden;
        width:  32%;
        float: right;   

    }
    &__womanimg{
        max-width: 100%;
    }
```

```html
<section>
        <div class="firstblock_background">
            1
            <div class="container">
                <div class="section">
                    <div class="section__menu">         
                        <ul class="section__ul">
                            <li >Главная</li>
                            <li id="imgline"> Содержание курса </li>
                            <li id="imgline"> Формат обучения </li>
                            <li id="imgline"> Купить курс </li>
                            <li id="imgline"> Контакты </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="section__text">
                        <p>Ваш учитель</p>
                        <p>начальных классов!</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="section__text2">
                        <p>УЧУ КАК НАДО!</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="section__woman">
                        <img src="source/block/woman.png" alt="" class="section__womanimg">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

upd: если сделать cover, то пустые места заменяются картинкой, но эффект тот же: блок растягивается на всю высоту экрана и мешает другим

Comment: Очевидно же - картинка с девушкой не меняет размера соответственно фону. Меняйте и ее тоже.

Comment: @Инквизитор даже если убрать девушку эти пробелы остаются, только что проверила

Comment: Добавьте к вопросу хотя бы часть разметки с картинкой

Comment: Попробуйте минимальное демо сделать в виде сниппета, или часть css вставьте

Answer (score 2):

Супер лайфхак - попробуй объединить фон с девушкой в одну картинку при помощи Photoshop например  Всё равно девушка как фон используется, а не как интерактивный элемент, так что какая разница...

Comment: Девушка должна быть так же адаптивной, заказчик хочет, чтобы первый блок выглядел одинаково и на мобильных, и на десктопе. Поэтому если сделаю фотошоп, то она не будет грамотно уменьшаться при уменьшении экрана

Comment: @talfaiz будет грамотно если сделаете через тег `<picture>` с использованием медиазапросов но на каждый стоп нужно делать свое изображение, и еще желательно в двух экземплярах - второй в webp формате. Если кажется что это не верный вариант то к примеру инстаграм так сделан. [picture doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Responsive_images)

Answer (score 1):

Вариантов решения много, не думаю что это лучший, это первый который в голову пришел. Лучше сделайте минимальное демо

В этом варианте есть проблема с просчетом 100vh, если не нужно чтоб был блок на 100высоты то поставьте другие величины, если нужно - есть фикс для мобильных [ФИКС](https://css-tricks.com/the-trick-to-viewport-units-on-mobile/)

```css
.hero{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

.img{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.img01{
  left: 0;
  background: url(https://placeimg.com/640/480/nature) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.img02{
top: unset;
  right: 0;
  width: 40vw;
  height: 50vh;
  background: url(https://placeimg.com/640/480/tech) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="hero">
<div class="img img01"></div>
<div class="img img02"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо всем!
Я поставила значение height не в px, а в vw и высота моего блока теперь равна фону. Все круто

Comment: Учтите что с 100vh есть проблемы на мобильном, особенно с айфонами (у них кроме верхней строки адресной есть нижняя) прочитайте [этот фикс](https://css-tricks.com/the-trick-to-viewport-units-on-mobile/) как сделать и для мобильных чтоб была на 100 по высоте